# How do I prove this these inequalities, preferably without calculus?

Tags: functions, derivatives, inequality

I'm trying to solve an inequality which stems from this problem:

If x, y, z are positive real numbers and $x^5+y^5+z^5=3$, prove $\frac{x^8}{y^3}+\frac{y^8}{z^3}+\frac{z^8}{x^3} \ge 3$

I thought that solving this directly would require an inequality I'm not familiar with, so I decided to set $y=ax$ and $z=bx$ (note $a>0$, $b>0$), reducing the inequality to be proven to:

$\frac{1}{a^3}+\frac{a^8}{b^3}+b^8≥1+a^5+b^5$ for all $a, b > 0$.

I tried proving it by proving the function $f$ with $f(a)=\frac{1}{a^3}+\frac{a^8}{b^3}+b^8≥1+a^5+b^5$ is always positive for $a>0$ and all $b>0$. I graphed it out, and noticed it only attained a value of zero when $a=1$ and $b=1$ (for values of b between 0 and 10). Afterwards, it seemed to only increase. However, the 11th degree polynomials are simply too much for me to handle.

So, my questions would be:

How do I prove the original inequality?

And how do I prove the inequality I have 'reduced' the original one to?

An answer without calculus and without advanced inequality identities would be preferred, but I would prefer an answer with them than no answer at all.

Comment: I'd recommend using Titu's lemma (a special case of the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality).

Answer (score 3):

Note that by the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) for triples $(x^3,y^3,z^3)$ and $(x^2,y^2,z^2)$ we can conclude that $$y^3x^2+z^3y^2+x^3z^2 \le x^5+y^5+z^5$$

Now by  [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)
$$(\frac{x^8}{y^3}+\frac{y^8}{z^3}+\frac{z^8}{x^3})(y^3x^2+z^3y^2+x^3z^2) \ge (x^5+y^5+z^5)^2 \implies$$  $$\frac{x^8}{y^3}+\frac{y^8}{z^3}+\frac{z^8}{x^3} \ge \frac{(x^5+y^5+z^5)^2}{y^3x^2+z^3y^2+x^3z^2} \ge \frac{(x^5+y^5+z^5)^2}{x^5+y^5+z^5} =x^5+y^5+z^5 = 3$$

Comment: It is “Schwarz” and not “Schwartz” – [Karl Hermann Amandus Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Schwarz)

Comment: If you're using rearrangement, $\sum_{cyc} \frac{x^8}{y^3}\geqslant \sum_{cyc} x^5$ can be obtained directly...

Comment: Note (I had to think on this for a moment) the rearrangement equality conditions are satisfied only because x, y, z > 0. So raising them all to any power preserves their order (whatever that order be). If they were not constrained positive, the square order might differ from the cube order.

Comment: @oly bit careful about the question!!! Or read it once again it. Question asked for positive reals

Comment: Btw!!! This is straight forward solution with LG which is a calculus approch I see now those who Don't know calculus it's hard for them so , The approach posted above is quiet good but I cannot give full point's though!!!